# Absence of release build optimizations in presence of OpenMP loop parallelization

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

The following snippet of C++ code presents a nested *for* loop, performing 3x3 matrix multiplication in the inner level.

```
int main()
{
    double sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: sum)
    for (int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        double eledir[3][3], noddir[3][3];

        for (int j=0;j<200000;++j)
        {
            eledir[0][0]=2*i+j; eledir[0][1]=2*i+j;
            eledir[0][2]=2*i+j; eledir[1][0]=4*i+j;
            eledir[1][1]=3*i+j; eledir[1][2]=4*i+j;
            eledir[2][0]=5*i+j; eledir[2][1]=6*i+j;
            eledir[2][2]=7*i+j;

            noddir[0][0]=2*i-2*j;   noddir[0][1]=1*i-2*j;
            noddir[0][2]=3*i-6*j;   noddir[1][0]=4*i-5*j;
            noddir[1][1]=5*i-2*j;   noddir[1][2]=4*i-4*j;
            noddir[2][0]=6*i-2*j;   noddir[2][1]=7*i-2*j;
            noddir[2][2]=8*i-3*j;

            //-- Matrix multiplication ----
            sum += mat_mul(eledir, noddir)/(sum+1);
        }
    }
    return (int) sum;
}
```

OpenMP used for parallelizing this regular loop using release build settings, does not show a linear speed-up with respect to the number of cores.

In particular, consider the inner loop in the code snippet takes about 4 msec in serial execution. When the outer loop is partitioned among 6 cores, then each inner loop takes about 30 msec, cancelling the speed-up achieved by parallelization and making it even slower than the serial code.

Comparing the timings with debug build, I learnt 30 msec is the time for execution of unoptimized inner loop. So for some reason, the optimizations do not happen in presence of openMP parallelization. Do you know why something like this happens, and how to avoid it?

The code example is simplified and reproduced from a non-trivial code.

```
double mat_mul(double a[3][3], double b[3][3])
{
    static double c[3][3];      

    c[0][0] = a[0][0]*b[0][0]+a[0][1]*b[1][0]+a[0][2]*b[2][0];
    c[0][1] = a[0][0]*b[0][1]+a[0][1]*b[1][1]+a[0][2]*b[2][1];
    c[0][2] = a[0][0]*b[0][2]+a[0][1]*b[1][2]+a[0][2]*b[2][2];

    c[1][0] = a[1][0]*b[0][0]+a[1][1]*b[1][0]+a[1][2]*b[2][0];
    c[1][1] = a[1][0]*b[0][1]+a[1][1]*b[1][1]+a[1][2]*b[2][1];
    c[1][2] = a[1][0]*b[0][2]+a[1][1]*b[1][2]+a[1][2]*b[2][2];

    c[2][0] = a[2][0]*b[0][0]+a[2][1]*b[1][0]+a[2][2]*b[2][0];
    c[2][1] = a[2][0]*b[0][1]+a[2][1]*b[1][1]+a[2][2]*b[2][1];
    c[2][2] = a[2][0]*b[0][2]+a[2][1]*b[1][2]+a[2][2]*b[2][2];

    return c[0][0]+c[0][1]+c[0][2]+c[1][0]+c[1][1]+c[1][2]+c[2][0]+c[2][1]+c[2][2];
}
```

Optimization flags in release build: /O2 (maximize speed), /Oi (enable interinsic functions), /GL (whole program optimization), /openmp to support OpenMP, Visual C++ compiler, Windows 7.

**UPDATE:** this problem is much less pronounced when using intel compiler (icc). But still not sure why this slow-down is happening when using MSVC++ and how to avoid it.

**UPDATE2:** as Mysticial pointed out, the issue is caused by "static" keyword in mat_mul. While using OpenMP, static variables should be treated with cautious. Removing "static" keyword solved the problem.

Comment: You do realize that making `c` static is gonna cause all the threads to clash over it right?

Comment: When there is no output, compiler optimizations simply avoid the computation. Initially I thought to use static to enforce the compiler no to bypass mat_mul execution, but it was not a smart way to deceive the compiler (it worked on VC++ but not on icc). so the code is changed in a way to produce an output. Static is removed.

Comment: Thank you @Mysticial, that was the reason, I just checked, and found after removing "static" keyword the inner loop takes about 4.2 msec.

Comment: "While using OpenMP, static variables should be treated with cautious" -- in fact, you shouldn't have been using in *at all*. `static` variables have a few legitimate use cases, and this isn't one.

Comment: Mind the flow dependence introduced by `sum += mat_mul(eledir, noddir)/(sum+1);`!

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev, in the example above, the output is totally trivial and is just served to avoid over-simplification imposed by compiler optimization.